# How to get System ringtones/sounds

Tags: react-native, push-notification, ringtone

How can i get the list of system ringtones or storage ringtones/sounds  in react native e.g ring tones, notification tones, so that i can give users choice to set them as notification tone?

I've searched some libraries but it didn't work

Comment: React Native doesn't support that out of the box, I suggest you look for a native library on Github, If you don't find one you'll have to implement it yourself natively (with Java/Kotlin for Android, objective-c for iOS) otherwise you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this module if you are using `Android`.  `react-native-ringtone-manager`

But it only use `Android` not `ios`

**Usage**

```js
import RingtoneManager from 'react-native-ringtone-manager';
...
getRings() {
 this.rings =  RingtoneManager.getRingtones(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALL);
 if(this.rings != null) {this.rings = this.rings.map((data,index) =>{<Text>{data.title}</Text>})};
}
```

Comment: and what we need to for ios ?

Comment: @SaloniParikh No modules are currently available for iOS. You have to make it yourself.

Comment: @SaloniParikh I posted my answer. If my answer was helpful, would you check the 'V' and the arrows to select the answer?

Comment: got undefined in RingtoneManager.getRingtones(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALL)

Comment: @SaloniParikh Did you do a react-native link ?

Answer (score 0):

For iOS I tried react-native-notification-sounds npm pacakge .. But it gives all the sounds from the sound folder .. So you get a long list of sounds and no way to filter which is notification or ringtone sound.. Working on this